# How do you set an accept attribute against an adminhtml form file input?

Tags: adminhtml, forms

I'm having trouble outputting an accept attribute to my Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form field, with a type of file.

I've got the following code:

```
class Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Model_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
protected function _prepareForm()
{
....
    $form->addField('attachment','file',array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('module')->__('Attach a file'),
        'name' => 'attachment',
        'required' => false
    ));
....
}
```

This is outputting the file input fine, however I need to restrict the extensions that can be uploaded, presumably with the accept=".doc" HTML attribute, however when I add the following:

```
$form->addField('attachment','file',array(
    'label' => Mage::helper('module')->__('Attach a file'),
    'name' => 'attachment',
    'required' => false,
    'accept' => '.doc'
));
```

It doesn't seem to output the accept attribute.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done a bit of digging and the problem seems to be coming from the Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract::getHtmlAttributes() method that builds the element, presumably the Abstract was wrote prior to HTML5 and the accept attribute hasn't been wrote into it.
For anyone else that comes across this problem, if you extend Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract::getHtmlAttributes() and update the returned array to include accept, it outputs fine.